# I need clues to study geometry (need resource to read)

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, plane-geometry, applications

I am an urban planning graduate with experience in related software. I found two topics regarding cities' plans interesting:

- Delaunay triangulation
- Voronoi diagram

Imagine! I can use *Voronoi diagram* in order to create zones based on the centers (these centers can be Hospital, Fire station, school, etc).

I am looking for more topics regarding geometry which are possible to apply in the 2D plane. In this case, I am not sure which topics, books, or resources I should research more. I would be appreciated if you **give me some reference** to read **or name a few diagrams or geometry topics** which it is possible to use in 2D plans.

Comment: Triangulation by Finite Elements Analysis to create Mesh (Hyper Mesh) may be a relevant source.

Comment: "Topics in geometry which are applicable in the euclidean plane" is a very broad category. Do you have any specific applications in mind?

Comment: you can try: Jiří Matoušek. Lectures on Discrete Geometry. Springer Graduate Texts in Mathematics. ISBN 0-387-95374-4  
But this topic is very broad, like you can abstract elements as points and their connections as arrows between them and come to graph theory with Dijkstras algorithm, the max-flow-min-cut-theorem, clarify what eulerian paths are and this is only what I remember from the top of my head from one course. And this is only algorithms, there's a whole world ahead of you

Comment: Thanks @WilliamA.Noble, I am looking for topics in geometry that are helping me to find better zoning in 2d plane, also another topic comes to my mind is using geometry to find better street network in cities.

Comment: Thank @Narasimham, It helps me a lot. It really inspires me.

Comment: Thanks @justabit, I search the two topics you mentioned and the book, at first glance it seems I can do lots of research in this area by following the book. It really inspires me. I appreciate your kindness.

Comment: What would "zoning" mean in this context? What I meant was, are you in a particular line of work that would benefit from this knowledge? The more specific you are about what you want, the better we can help you. Maybe you could provide a list of what interests you. As of right now your request is still very vague.

Comment: **GIS** is also useful

Comment: An enjoyable read that gives some sense of the scope of mathematical modeling in urban planning can be found at https://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/life-in-the-city-is-essentially-one-giant-math-problem-37759041/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer to zoning, I assume you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoning). Unless you specify what you're trying to optimize for and in what context you intend to apply the knowledge you seek, I cannot give you any better recommendations. In fact, this is a question that is better suited for the [Engineering StackExchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/), where you will find civil engineers and perhaps other urban planners such as yourself that might have experience dealing with issues such as this and thus could give you guidance that is a bit more focused than you will find here. If you were to ask your question there and then come back here with more specific requests, I'm sure we would be able to better assist you (for example, if you wanted to optimize for traffic flow, I could point you to [traffic flow theory](http://helper.ipam.ucla.edu/publications/tratut/tratut_12985.pdf)).

Having said that, [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), as @justabit has mentioned, and in particular the [four color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) could be of interest to you. Start with the wikipedia articles and, if you feel like there might be something to it, there are a variety of different books on the topic (Springer's *Graduate Texts in Mathematics* collection offers you a few good picks); fair warning, most of them will be quite advanced. Graph theory is a part of discrete mathematics, about which a book has already been recommended to you (the book justabit recommended includes a section on Voronoi diagrams and mentions the Delaunay triangulation, in case you haven't checked it out yet).

I have also found [this](https://www.somacon.com/p119.php) article, which touches very lightly on a few ideas that you might enjoy. Check out the bibliography at the end of the page  and see if the writings/authors have anything worthwhile to offer you (in particular Nikos Salingaros).

Lastly, a quick web search of "mathematics of urban planning" will produce a variety of results, some of which you may find worth looking into.

I don't know if these recommendations will be helpful to you, but I hope this will at least give you *some* idea about where to start looking. There's a lot to learn on nodes and the connections between them through graph theory, for example. Keep in mind that as someone whose background is in mathematics only I have no idea how you might (or if you could, even) apply these. I will again recommend that you pose this question to the civil engineers on the Engineering SE.

Comment: Thanks William, Yes the link you mentioned about zoning was correct and it clearly mentioned my idea about zoning.  Another question is how graph theory can be used in zoning? I think it's most likely to use it in routing and navigation in cities. For example Triangulation by Finite Elements Analysis looks most likely to use it for zoning purpose.  By the way, based on the links and item you mentioned I found lots of clue which I need to follow and read more about them. Secially Nikos Salingaros is perfect.

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei As I mentioned, I don't really have the background necessary to help you apply this knowledge. I wish I could be of more help in that regard. If you could tell me one or more specific applications for which you'd like some resources, I (or someone else) might be able to find better recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As a start, *Mathematica* creates a planar mesh of cardinal  points defined with their respective heights.

Comment: Thanks Narasimham. every mesh cell is 1*1 or I can apply any login that I prefer. Also, this software, I didn't heard about that, Can I import map in this software?

Comment: I think different scales can be chosen; you need to buy and install this software if you are not a student.  Btw Delaunay Mesh is also available on Mathematica.

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei Mathematica was developed by Wolfram and you can find out more about it [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)